# WindowsCE project, compile and deploy

Tags: visual-studio, windows-ce

I have a several years old project written for WindowsCE that I need to rebuild and deploy it to a device.

When I try to open the project it starts Visual Studio 2008 and reports error that it can't open projects inside because .vddproj and .csproj are not supported.

What I need to install to be able to open these projects?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have C# and Smart Device Programmability installed with Visual Studio?  You might have to go back to the install media and update the installation to ensure those pieces are included.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do have C# installed, not sure about others, will download the installation and run it.